# While Loop - Separate Title From Looped Results - Loop and Then Title For Each Set Of Results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop which separates all the linked numbers into different sections in a table.  Here is the statement:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM b_statement_main a 
INNER JOIN b_crm_company b ON a.COMPANY_ID = b.ID INNER JOIN b_statement c 
ON a.LINK = c.LINK 
WHERE a.COMPANY_ID = '$companyID2' AND a.COMMENCE BETWEEN '$from2' AND '$to2' ");

$linked = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{

    $companyName = $row['TITLE'];
    $arDates = strtotime($row['COMMENCE']);
    $remaining = $row['REMAINING_HOURS'];
    $linking = $row['LINK'];
    $arNumber = $row['REF_NUMBER'];
    $billable = $row['BILLABLE'];


    if($linked != $row['LINK'])
    {
    print "<tr><td><strong>$companyName</strong></td><td></td><td><strong>".date('d/m/Y',$arDates)."</strong></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>$remaining</strong></td></tr>";

    $linked = $row['LINK'];
    }

    print "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>$arNumber</td><td>$billable</td><td></td></tr>";

}

print "</table>";
```

So what this returns is a title for each section and then it loops the results related to the query below.  Once it has returned all the respective results it will then display the title section again and loop the related results again.  It will repeat this until everything has been displayed.

However what I wanting is for the title section to be below the looping results.  So, therefore it will loop the results and then once it has looped them all for that particular section, put the title underneath.  It will then go in and loop the results again and put the title underneath and it will carry on until it is completed.

Anybody have any idea how I can do this.  Obviously if I move the print before the if, then it puts the result, title, result, title etc.

So this is what it looks like at the moment (not accurate but just to show the title and the results):

```
| Company  | Date        | Hours |
| Title 1  | 20/11/2014  |       |
| Result 1 | 10/11/2014  | 44    |
| Result 2 | 08/11/2014  | 22    |
```

When I need it like:

```
| Company  | Date        | Hours |
| Result 1 | 10/11/2014  | 44    |
| Result 2 | 08/11/2014  | 22    |
| Title 1  | 20/11/2014  |       |
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new array based upon the entries you want in the table.  So your code would go something like (note `$outputarray` was added):

**Edit: This assumes there is only one Title per data set.**  If you want more than one title per set of records, you need to set something in the record that identifies a set.  In this case, the easiest way was to make a multi-dimension array of the results, based upon if it was a title or not (by your criteria).

```
$linked = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){    
    $companyName = $row['TITLE'];
    $arDates = strtotime($row['COMMENCE']);
    $remaining = $row['REMAINING_HOURS'];
    $linking = $row['LINK'];
    $arNumber = $row['REF_NUMBER'];
    $billable = $row['BILLABLE'];

    if($linked != $row['LINK']){
       $outputarray['title'][] ="<tr><td><strong>$companyName</strong></td>
          <td></td><td><strong>".date('d/m/Y',$arDates)."</strong></td><td></td><td>
          </td><td><strong>$remaining</strong></td></tr>";
       $linked = $row['LINK'];
    } else {
       $outputarray['row'][]= "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>$arNumber</td>
          <td>$billable</td><td></td></tr>";
    }
  }
   print"<table>
         <thead>"; // etc... have the titles go here.
   foreach($outputarray as $key=> $value){
        if($key=='title'){
          $thistitle=$value;
        } else {
          print $value;
        }
   }
   print $thistitle;

   print "</table>";
```

Comment: That displays the result exactly the same as how I have it at the moment

Comment: What is a link has multiple titles?  Would you only display one title?  You could split the two arrays (such as `$outputarrayTitle` and `$outputarrayContent`, and print them separately.  But the data coming from the query may not match your vision.

Comment: The title will always separate results, I've edited my question to show you what I mean at the bottom

Comment: It isn't clear how your output is being split.  You have a column in your query that outputs both `Result` and `Title`?  How is it that if the `$linked != $row['LINK']` it becomes a title?  Or is that backwards?

Comment: Yes the `$linked != $row['LINK']` always displays the title. When $linked = $row['LINK'] then it displays all the results with the same number in LINK in the database table.

Comment: I edited to make it a multidimensional array.  Please check the note; this assumes that you only have one title returned for the entire query.